# Updating Powerpoint Graph 2010 from Excel 2010

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to update Powerpoint Graph 2010 from Excel 2010. 
Code looks for the Objects and finds the range with name similar in powerpoint, it applies changes to the graph. Graph format should be same only data must be updated.

Code is as follow, it is not able to find charts, either able to update it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX = "Export_"
Private Const NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX_TEXT = "ExportText"
Private m_sLog As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo Catch

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim mgrChart As Chart
Dim mgrDatasheet As Graph.DataSheet

Dim rngData As Excel.Range

Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
Dim sTag As String
Dim nFound As Long, nUpdated As Long
Dim nFoundText As Long, nUpdatedText As Long

Dim i As Integer

Dim fLog As frmLog

Dim Box1Status As VbMsgBoxResult

m_sLog = ""

'Prompt to Export
Box1Status = MsgBox("Export and Save to Powerpoint Template?" & Chr(13) & "Reminder: Please use a clean template for export and be sure to back up the template beforehand. " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "PLEASE SAVE ANY OTHER OPEN POWERPOINT DOCUMENTS AS ALL UNSAVED WORK WILL BE LOST!", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Export")
If Box1Status = vbNo Then Exit Sub


i = 1

UpdateStatus "Opening Powerpoint presentation '" & Range("fileloc")
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pptApp.Activate
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(Range("fileloc"))
pptApp.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized

'Looks for (tagged) charts to update

UpdateStatus "Searching presentation for charts..."
For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides

    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes


       If pptShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then

       If TypeOf pptShape.OLEFormat.Object Is Graph.Chart Then

                nFound = nFound + 1

                Set mgrChart = pptShape.OLEFormat.Object

                Set mgrChart = pptShape.Chart


                Set mgrDatasheet = mgrChart.Application.DataSheet
                With mgrDatasheet
                    sTag = .Cells(1, 1)
                    If Left(sTag, 6) = "Export" Then UpdateStatus "Found chart on slide '" & pptSlide.SlideNumber & "' with tag '" & sTag & "'. Searching Excel workbook for same tag..."
                    Set rngData = RangeForChart(sTag)
                    If rngData Is Nothing Then
                      ' This chart has no data in this Excel workbook
                        If Left(sTag, 6) <> "Export" Then
                            UpdateStatus "Found chart on slide '" & pptSlide.SlideNumber & "' with no tag, skipping"
                        Else
                            UpdateStatus "'" & sTag & "' does not exist in workbook, skipping."
                        End If
                    Else
                      ' Update the PowerPoint chart with the Excel data
                        UpdateStatus "Found '" & sTag & "' at named range '" & rngData.Name & "'. Updating presentation..."
                        .Cells.ClearContents
                        For iRow = 0 To rngData.Rows.Count - 1
                            For iCol = 0 To rngData.Columns.Count - 1
                                .Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = rngData.Cells(iRow + 1, iCol + 1)
                            Next iCol
                        Next iRow
                        .Application.Update
                        UpdateStatus "Chart with tag '" & sTag & "' updated."
                        nUpdated = nUpdated + 1
                    End If
                End With
                Set mgrDatasheet = Nothing
                mgrChart.Application.Quit
                Set mgrChart = Nothing
           End If
       'End If
    Next pptShape
  i = i + 1
Next pptSlide


UpdateStatus "Finished searching presentation. Closing PowerPoint."

pptPresentation.Save
pptPresentation.Close
Set pptPresentation = Nothing
pptApp.Quit
Set pptApp = Nothing

UpdateStatus "Done. " & nFound & " charts found and " & nUpdated & " charts updated. " & nFoundText & " text boxes found and " & nUpdatedText & " text boxes updated."

Set fLog = New frmLog
fLog.Caption = "Update of Powerpoint Template Complete"
fLog.txtLog.Text = m_sLog
fLog.Show
Unload fLog
Set fLog = Nothing
Exit Sub

Catch:
MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred while updating: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical
ForceCleanup mgrChart, mgrDatasheet, pptPresentation, pptApp
End Sub

Private Property Get RangeForChart(sTag As String) As Range
Dim sChartTag As String
Dim iUpdate As Long
Dim NameList As Range
'Dim nRow As Range

Set NameList = Range("Name_List")

If Left(sTag, 6) <> "Export" Then Exit Property

'For Each nRow In NameList.Rows
Do While sChartTag <> sTag

    iUpdate = iUpdate + 1
  ' This will error if there is no named range for "Export_", which means that sTag does not
  ' exist in the workbook so return nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        sChartTag = ActiveWorkbook.Names(NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX & NameList(iUpdate, 1).Value).RefersToRange.Cells(1, 1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          ' Return nothing
            Exit Property
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
'Next nRow


Set RangeForChart = ActiveWorkbook.Names(NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX & NameList(iUpdate, 1).Value).RefersToRange

End Property

Private Property Get RangeForText(sTag As String) As Range
Dim sTextTag As String
Dim iUpdate As Long

If Left(sTag, 10) <> "ExportText" Then Exit Property

Do While sTextTag <> sTag
    iUpdate = iUpdate + 1
  ' This will error if there is no named range for "ExportText" & iUpdate, which means that sTag does not
  ' exist in the workbook so return nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        sTextTag = NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX_TEXT & iUpdate
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          ' Return nothing
            Exit Property
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop

Set RangeForText = ActiveWorkbook.Names(NAMED_RANGE_PREFIX_TEXT & iUpdate).RefersToRange

End Property

Private Sub UpdateStatus(sMessage As String)
m_sLog = m_sLog & Now() & ": " & sMessage & vbNewLine
Application.StatusBar = Now() & ": " & sMessage
DoEvents
End Sub

Private Sub ForceCleanup(mgrChart As Graph.Chart, mgrDatasheet As Graph.DataSheet, pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation, pptApp As PowerPoint.Application)
On Error Resume Next
mgrChart.Application.Quit
Set mgrChart = Nothing
mgrDatasheet.Application.Quit
Set mgrDatasheet = Nothing
pptPresentation.Close
Set pptPresentation = Nothing
pptApp.Quit
Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a bunch of code for this.

Build the charts in Excel, copy them, go to PowerPoint, use Paste Special - Link. Change the data in Excel, and the Excel charts update. Then open the PowerPoint presentation, and if necessary, update links.

Answer (score 0):

In the data sheet for your powerpoint graph, you can "link" the cells to your excel data file by typing in one of the cells (path and file name are made up here)
=c:\PPTXfiles\excelfiles[excelfiles.xlsx]sheetname'!a1
This will create a link that doesn't show up in the links section of powerpoint, but can be updated just by opening both files and double clicking on the chart to activate it.
Sometime the paste by link feature isn't feasible to use since the end user of the file wants to "break it up" and send out parts.  That is not possible without the source excel file, since the end users want to be able to edit the chart or the data.

If you can do this and then copy and paste the data sheet by values in VBA, before sending to the enduser that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Bam!

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim ExcelFile
    Dim exl As Object
    Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

     'Open a dialog box to promt for the new source file.
    ExcelFile = exl.Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Excel File")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

     'Go through every slide
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
             'Go through every shape on every slide
            For k = 1 To .Shapes.Count
                'Turn of error checking s that it doesn 't crash if the current shape doesn't already have a link
                On Error Resume Next
                 'Set the source to be the same as teh file chosen in the opening dialog box
                .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile
                If .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile Then
                     'If the change was successful then also set it to update automatically
                    .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.Update
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next k
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```